# Factoring $x^n + 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, polynomial-rings

By the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, every polynomial of degree $n$ can be factored into a product of $n$ linear polynomials.

As an example, since the polynomial $ x^5 +1$ has the five complex roots $$\tag{1} -1,\quad e^{\frac{\pi i}{5}}, \quad  e^{\frac{-\pi i}{5}}, \quad  e^{\frac{3\pi i}{5}}, \quad  e^{\frac{-3\pi i}{5}},$$ we can write $$\tag{2} x^5+1=(x+1)(x- e^{\frac{\pi i}{5}})(x- e^{\frac{-\pi i}{5}})(x- e^{\frac{3\pi i}{5}})(x- e^{\frac{-3\pi i}{5}}).$$

Multiplying several terms in $(2)$ gives $$\tag{3} x^5+1=(x+1)(x^2 -2\cos{\frac{\pi}{5}}x + 1)(x^2 -2\cos{ \frac{3\pi}{5}}x+1).$$

Now, $(3)$ is of course a specific example of the general theorem (which also relies on the structure of $\mathbb{C}$):

> Any polynomial with real coefficients can be factored into a product of real linear and real quadratic polynomials.

Generalising $(3)$ to any odd value  $n\in \mathbb{N}$, gives the following formula:
$$\tag{4} x^n +1 = (x+1) \left(x^2 -2\big(\cos{\frac{\pi}{n}}\big)x + 1\right) \left(x^2 -2\big(\cos{\frac{3\pi}{n}}\big)x + 1\right)\cdots \left(x^2 -2\big(\cos{\frac{(n-2)\pi}{n}}\big)x + 1\right) .$$

This result is interesting to me, as it suggests that even in $\mathbb{R}$ the cosine function is, in some vague sense, built in to exponentiation.

**Question:** I am wondering if either the general formula $(4)$ or a specific case, such as $(3)$, could be derived using only real analytical tools (and maybe some ring theory?): i.e., without complex numbers and Euler’s formula?

Comment: any polynomial with real coefficients factors into a product of real polynomials, some linear and some quadratic, no need for degree larger than two. This happens because the roots occur in complex conjugate pairs. Meanwhile, it is no easier to work out such a real factoring than the full complex factoring... given one of the factors $x^2 + bx + c$ with $b^2 - 4c < 0,$ we can reconstruct the complex roots by the quadratic formula

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that theorem (I stated it in my post). I am wondering if the specific case $x^n + 1$, for odd numbers $n$, could conceivably have been discovered without complex numbers, i.e., if there is anything in the structure of $\mathbb{R}$ which would suggest the formula $(4)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case $\,n=5\,$ can be solved algebraically by first factoring $\,x^5+1$ $ = (x+1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)\,$, then the second factor is a [palindromic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial) which reduces to a quadratic in $\,x+1/x\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1 &= x^2\left(\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)+1\right) \\
 &= x^2\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 - \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right) - 1\right) \\
 &= x^2\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)-z_1\right)\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)-z_2\right) \\
 &= \left(x^2-z_1 x + 1\right)\left(x^2-z_2 x + 1\right)
\end{align}
$$

In the latter $\,z_{1,2}=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}\,$ are the roots of $\,z^2-z-1=0\,$, and the expression matches the trigonometric form. In fact, this is one way to prove that $\,\cos \dfrac{\pi}{5}=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}\,$.

Similarly, the case $\,n=7\,$ factors as:

$$
x^7+1=(x+1)\left(x^2-z_1 x + 1\right)\left(x^2-z_2 x + 1\right)\left(x^2-z_3 x + 1\right)
$$

Here $\,z_{1,2,3}\,$ are the roots of the cubic $\,z^3-z^2-2z+1=0\,$.

For odd $\,n\,$ the problem reduces to factoring a polynomial of degree $\,\dfrac{n-1}{2}\,$, however that is not solvable by radicals in general for $\,n \gt 9\,$.